# How do I avoid the "No GPS connection" message?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have an active GPS connection, but the game doesn't allow me to play because it always shows "No GPS connection". What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Find a place with a clear view of the sky. GPS is ground to satellite communication, so if there's something in between you and the space above you, that communication may not work well.

In case it's not obvious, you definitely want to be outside. If you are in a valley surrounded by mountains, you may have trouble, because sometimes the satellites are low in the sky and are blocked by the mountains. Finally, thunderstorms and other severe weather can cause trouble with ground to satellite communication. Wait for any storms to pass.

Comment: Cities with big buildings can also cause issues.

Comment: Furthermore there are extern GPS receivers for smartphone if its a hardware issue.

Comment: Also try to enable Wifi for a while. It actually helps the gps to get faster lock (by pinging nearby routers) and then you can turn it off.